# zfs: dataset does not exist

Tags: debian, zfs, zfsonlinux

I'm not able to set mountpoint to the pool.

`# zpool import`

```
   pool: wd-black
     id: 18120690490361195109
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

        wd-black      ONLINE
          crypted-wd  ONLINE
```

Pool is normally visible and I'm able to import it into some direcotory. But I can't set nor get mountpoint:

```
# zfs set mountpoint=/ wd-black
cannot open 'wd-black': dataset does not exist
```

Can you say me why I have this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be *zpool import **wd-black***. As it is, you have displayed a list of importable pools, not importing any.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you didn't import the pool. Furthermore, I think you don't want to set a *mountpoint* to / unless you import the pool with `-o altroot` key.

Answer (score 1):

You would then import the dataset by name:

```
zpool import wd-black
```

With any luck, you can then:

```
zfs mount -a
```